# How to catch a templateUrl load error

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Assuming that the request for the template of a component, can't be delivered (status code 400, etc..), is there a way to catch the error in order to take an action (redirect, etc...)

Thanks.

Comment: may be there is some `http` interceptor, which could help to find there is an error while fetching anything over `http` protocol..

Comment: @PankajParkar What I would like to have was some kind of a fallback in case of an error, assuming that I had a dashboard and one of the components couldn't be rendered, I could use a "static" template saying "Error", instead of "breaking" the app. Probably something like the $templateRequest in angular1...

Comment: @JoãoAugusto isn't sound like `$rotueChangeError` event in Angular1?

Comment: @PankajParkar I'm on the same route. Just with many components, and I would like to have a "inline static error" template in case one of the templates can't be obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that the question is very old, but today we have a better solution.

Angular provides a class called `ResourceLoader` that you can extend and create your own implementation overriding the base behavior.

I'm created a `CustomResourceLoader` that extends from `ResourceLoader` to insert tokens on `templateUrl` request, because my pages are provided by a server.

So, you can use this to catch errors and make what you want.

You can see the angular implementation of `ResourceLoader` on [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/platform-browser-dynamic/src/resource_loader/resource_loader_impl.ts) link, and a example of how extend correctly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46345567/6679681).

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am not aware of a way to do a catch in the `templateUrl`.

What we can do, as a workaround, is making an `head` request to check if the file exists.

So, your component would look something like this:

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';

let hasTemplate = function(template: string) {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open('HEAD', template, false);
  http.send();
  return (http.status===200) ? template : 'error.html';    
}

@Component({
  selector: 'your-component'
})
@View({
  templateUrl: hasTemplate('your-template.html')
})
export class YourComponent {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

I know this is not a optimum solution. But for the time being I think its an easy workaround that will allow you to make a fallback in case the template file isn't present.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is currently (beta.2) no such mechanism.

You can check the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/db87baeb98be5d9c94ba447d444a134d116d2522/modules/angular2/src/compiler/template_normalizer.ts#L34) of the `normalizeTemplate` method that fetches the template, I don't think there is a way to plug some logic if an error happens.

Answer (score 0):

Using angular2's new resolver you can pre-fetch data before loading the template. I suppose you can use the same mechanism to prefetch the template, even if you just throw it away. In the catch block you can redirect if there is some problem with the request.

There is good information and a nice example at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard, which I included below in case something happens to the link.

```
import { Injectable }             from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Resolve,
         ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable }             from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Crisis, CrisisService } from './crisis.service';
@Injectable()
export class CrisisDetailResolve implements Resolve<Crisis> {
  constructor(private cs: CrisisService, private router: Router) {}
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
    let id = +route.params['id'];
    return this.cs.getCrisis(id).then(crisis => {
      if (crisis) {
        return crisis;
      } else { // id not found
        this.router.navigate(['/crisis-center']);
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```