# How to intercept request to component html templates in Angular 4.3.5

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

I need to intercept request to the html component templates. Angular version is `4.3.5`.

I tried to achieve it with implementing interceptors as described in angular httpClient manual (https://angular.io/guide/http) like that

interceptor.service.js

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Get the auth header from the service.
    const authHeader = this.auth.getAuthorizationHeader();
    // Clone the request to add the new header.
    const authReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', authHeader)});
    // Pass on the cloned request instead of the original request.
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

app.module.js

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: NoopInterceptor,
    multi: true,
  }],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

but it intercepts http requests from services and components which i wrote by myself but doesn't intercept requests to html templates which are made by angular.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413026/using-directiveresolver-to-alter-component-metadata

Comment: @yurzui i want to add custom parameter in the end of request url to prevent caching issues

Comment: How do you build your application?

Comment: @yurzui `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(Ng2App)` where `Ng2App` is main application module

Comment: angular-cli, webpack, systemjs?

Comment: i am using systemjs

Comment: Are you using aot?

Comment: @yurzui no, i don't use aot. I will try to use `ResourceLoader`, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can have access to `@angular/compiler` then try to override `ResourceLoader`:

**main.ts**

```typescript
platformBrowserDynamic([{
    provide: COMPILER_OPTIONS,
    useValue: { providers: [{ 
                  provide: ResourceLoader, 
                  useClass: CustomResourceLoader, 
                  deps: [] 
              }]
    },
    multi: true
}]).bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/5Z9DI9JMkePjD7f4CDSr?p=preview)**